# Open liberty and Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, open-liberty

Can I use Hibernate as JPA implementation in open-liberty? If such integration exists, I would presume that it comes with distributed caching and JTA?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, in OpenLiberty we have the `jpaContainer-2.1` feature, which provides *only the JPA container integration code*, and allows the user to plug in their own JPA 2.1 compliant implementation (i.e. EclipseLink or Hibernate).

Specifically for Hibernate, the `jpaContainer-2.1` feature will integrate Hibernate with Liberty's transaction manager. See [LibertyJtaPlatform](https://github.com/OpenLiberty/open-liberty/blob/master/dev/com.ibm.ws.jpa.container.core/src/com/ibm/ws/jpa/hibernate/LibertyJtaPlatform.java)

You can find full documentation here, including config examples: 
[Deploying a JPA application to Liberty](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS7K4U_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.zseries.doc/ae/twlp_dep_jpa.html)

The basic config you will need in server.xml is the following:

```
<featureManager>
   <feature>jpaContainer-2.1</feature>
   <feature>bells-1.0</feature>
      ...    
</featureManager>    

<!-- Making a 'bell' for the library will register any META-INF/services in the referenced library with the Liberty runtime -->
<bell libraryRef="hibernate"/>

<!-- Include all of the hibernate jars in a shared lib -->
<library id="hibernate">
    <fileset dir="${server.config.dir}/hibernate/" includes="*.jar"/>
</library>

<!-- OPTIONAL: If you wish to directly reference hibernate APIs in your app, you will need to configure a shared library classloader -->
<application location="myApp.war">
   <classloader commonLibraryRef="hibernate"/>
</application>
```

Comment: Thanks Andy, the only thing I am still unclear about is the configuration of Hibernate's second level cache. Typically this is is done with Infinispan, or in case of Payara - nazelcast. How is this done in OpenLiberty?

Comment: @HristoStoyanov I have not configured Hibernate's session factory cache before, but if I had to guess... you will need to provide your own implementation (for instance Ehcache) since I don't think youll find one in OpenLiberty. Then add it to the shared library in your server config and set the persistence properties Hibernate needs.

Comment: Thanks Will,I figured that I had to do something like that

Comment: Will configurations be the same if I'm using jpaContainer-2.2?