# Unable to integrate openliberty,JPA with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, open-liberty

I'm trying to use JPA, Hibernate with OpenLiberty to develop a JakartaEE Application.

I followed this document: https://openliberty.io/guides/jpa-intro.html#configuring-jpa

In my case, I'm hoping to use either jpaContainer-2.2 or jpa-2.2.

Some of the code snippets are as below,

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<persistence version="2.2"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
                        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="jpaunit" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/recruittimesdb</jta-data-source>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

server.xml

```
<dataSource id="hibernatemysqldb"
        jndiName="jdbc/recruittimesdb">
        <jdbcDriver libraryRef="MySQLLib" />
        <properties databaseName="recruit_times_db"
            serverName="localhost" password="admin1234" user="root"
            serverTimezone="UTC" portNumber="3306" />
    </dataSource>

    <library id="MySQLLib">
        <file
            name="C:/Users/harsha/Documents/mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar" />
    </library>

    <library id="hibernate">
        <fileset dir="${config.dir}/hibernate/"
            includes="*.jar" />
    </library>
```

I'm still not able to integrate Hibernate successfully. It would be great to see a working example.

**UPDATE:**

When the server starts up, I get this error.

```
[INFO] [ERROR   ] CWWJP0015E: An error occurred in the org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider persistence provider when it attempted to create the container entity manager factory for the jpaunit
```

persistence unit. The following error occurred: [PersistenceUnit: jpaunit] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory

Comment: If you are using Hibernate with OpenLiberty you will want to use the `jpaContainer-2.2` feature (which just includes JPA integrations) and not the `jpa-2.2` feature (which includes JPA integrations + EclipseLink)

Comment: also, please update your question with the error you are seeing. Here is a pointer to the config needed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47396524/3814029

Comment: I tried this too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47396310/open-liberty-and-hibernate/47396524#47396524, but no luck.

Comment: hi @AndyGuibert, sorry for the late reply, is there a way to use Hibernate with <feature>javaee-8.0</feature> ? or as you said earlier do I need to enable only jpaContainer-2.2 ?

Comment: there isn't a way to use Hibernate with javaee-8.0 because it pulls in jpa-2.2 which pulls in EclipseLink. So yes you'd need to enable only jpaContianer-2.2 and any other specific features that your app needs

Comment: I was able to do it,https://www.harshajayamanna.com/2020/08/openliberty-jakartaee8-and-hibernate.html